# How does this rails route match any incoming action to it's correlated method on the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails route defined like this:

`match '/test_report(/:action)' => 'test_report#index', via: :all`

I am not an expert on Rails routing, but using context clues I would have expected that this route to map any request like `/test_report/some_action` or `/test_report/other_action` to the `index` method on the `TestReportController`, because of the part of the route definition after the hash rocket: `=> 'test_report#index'`.

However, this is not the behavior. Instead, I can create another method on the `TestReportController` called `update_report`, and then I can `POST` to `/test_report/update_report` to trigger the `update_report` method. From the route definition I'm using, I wouldn't expect this to work, but it does. I would have expected the `POST` to hit the `index` method on the controller.

Note: Just so we're clear, I do understand that the `(/:action)` part of the route marks it as an optional part of the URL, and the `:action` symbol is special here and is interpreted as an action's name.

**TL;DR**:

If the `=> 'test_report#index'` in the above route doesn't map all requests to the `index` method on the controller, what does it actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, whatever parameters you define within the route pattern become available in the `params` hash in the controller.

So in your example, `:action` becomes available within the controller as `params[:action]`, which is also used internally by Rails to load the correct action. (If you inspect, you'll see `params[:route]`, `params[:controller]`, `params[:action]`, etc.)

I'm guessing that defining your own `:action` in the URL pattern like that causes Rails to prefer that over what's in your mapping (skipping the `index` in `test_report#index`).

If you want to live in both worlds, you'll probably want to name it something other than `:action`.

Comment: I used the word `redirect` in quotes in the post because I didn't mean a literal HTTP redirect. I don't think you understood the question. I edited the question to be less confusing about this.

Comment: @manroe I see what you're asking. I hope my rewritten answer addresses your real question better.

Comment: thanks for the edit. what you're describing sounds reasonable - maybe the `index` action defined in the `'test_report#index'` mapping is overridden by the action in the URL via `(/:action)`.

Comment: regarding "living in both worlds", I'm actually happy with the current behavior, but wanted to understand it. Thanks to you, I've realized the "correct" way for me to define the route would be like this:
`match '/test_report(/:action)', controller:'test_report', via: :all`
because this would avoid the inclusion of the `index` action completely.

Comment: Yeah, I think your updated code would potentially make it clearer to reason about too. The only problem that I see with it is there is not default action if you leave the `:action` out of the URL. I'd image that the line in your original post handles that scenario.